# Multiple validation functions in cakephp model class

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a login form and a registration form . And both are attached to same table users. How do i validate both forms seperately in Model class. I have tried with two different functions, the code is below

```
class User extends AppModel
{
public function login()
  {
    public $private = array('username'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Username is reqired . So please fill the username')),'password'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please enter your password.')));
    }
public function register()
    {
        public $private = array('firstname'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Enter your first name'),'lastname'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Enter your lastname name'),'username'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Username is reqired . So please fill the username')),'password'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please enter your password.')),'role'=>array('valid'=>array('rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),'message' => 'Please enter a valid role','allowEmpty' => false))));
    }
}
```

My doubt is how wil the controller know which function is for login or register. How do i need to write the code in controller to call this ????

Comment: a) dont make it private  b) usually you have one common `public $validate` array here. Try to read the docs about validation.

Comment: But with only one $validate how can i validate 2 forms ?

Comment: you don't validate the form, you validate the data. Cake doesn't care where the data comes from, providing it is in the correct format. Whatever data is provided to your model, cake will validate it

Comment: @Ross Thanks and if i dnt use 2 functions and write all validations for $validate will it work?

Comment: You need one `public $validate` array containing all of your fields and the associated rules. When you `$this->Model->save($data)` cake will validate it. This is basic cake principles and covered thoroughly in the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this may work :-

```
class User extends AppModel
{

    public $private = array('firstname'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Enter your first name'),'lastname'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Enter your lastname name'),'username'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Username is reqired . So please fill the username')),'password'=>array('required'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please enter your password.')),'role'=>array('valid'=>array('rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),'message' => 'Please enter a valid role','allowEmpty' => false))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validateLogin = array(
       // validate rules for the login form submission
    );

    public $validateRegister = array(
        // validate rules for the registration form submission
    );

}

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function login() {

        $this->User->validate = $this->User->validateLogin;

        // handle login form submission

    }

    public function register() {

        $this->User->validate = $this->User->validateRegister;

        // handle register form submission

    }

}
```